# Constrain scene navigation in AFrame

Tags: three.js, aframe

I am building an application in AFrame and I want to constrain the viewers movement, that is I want to limit where the camera can go in the scene. For example I have a a-plane that is the floor and I want the camera to stop moving when it reaches 0 on the Z axis to stop the camera from going through the floor or stop again if it reaches 20 on Z axis. I also wish to limit the movement in x,y directions. There are no obstacles in the scene besides the a-plane. Is creating a navigation mesh my only option or is there an easier way to constrain movement? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of built in tools to do this, but you could do it with programming (this sounds pretty easy). You could create a custom component, attached to the camera, with a tick handler, that records the position of the camera in world space and stores in in a variable (camPosPrevFrame). Then create a function to test if the current position is outside of the bounds. If so, set the camera coordinate on the axis that has exceeded its limit, to the previously recorded boundary (camPosPrevFrame). If you are simply testing whether the camera is on one side of an orthagonal plane (say the world space xy plane), that is pretty simple math (camera.getWorldPosition.x>someAmount). If you have a more complex situation, there are ways to test if a point is on either side of any arbitrary plane (it involves the dot product).